# Set embedded image to image control in rdlc with condition

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, rdlc

I have a rdlc report and some embedded images. I need in image control set one of my embedded images with conditional result. I'm trying to set in image control with an expression but and obviously it doesn't work:

```
=IIf(Mid(First(Fields!numero.Value, "dsRecetasXML"), 2) = "03", 
         formatorecetaalicante, formatorecetamurciadentista)
```

I read this can be done with external images but I prefer to use embedded images.. it is possible?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using two different image box with embedded image linked to them, but making the visibility of your image box based on your condition.

Comment: Hi @Gautam, could you expand on your answer a bit?